# What does 2+common walls mean in this ad?

Tags: word-meaning

> Interior features
>
> - 2 story
> - security features: gated community
>
> Building and construction
>
> - floor: partially carpeted
> - common walls: **2+ common walls**
> - levels or stories: 2
> - attached structure: attached

Could you simplify the **2 plus** and **common walls**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *common* wall is one which your dwelling shares with another one - that is, your apartment is on one side of the wall and someone else's is on the other side.

*2+* means that each apartment shares at least two walls with other apartments, and it may share more, depending on where it is located in the building.